# Circular dependency detected in Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-ngmodel, angular-module

I have the following app structure in my Angular 7 app:

```
AppModule
DashboardModule
  DashboardChild1
  DashboardChild2
  DashboardChild3
  DashboardService
AdminModule
  AdminChild1
  AdminChild2
  AdminChild3
```

and I want to have DashboardService available only in the `DashboardModule`, so I followed this link [providedin-and-ngmodules](https://angular.io/guide/providers#providedin-and-ngmodules).

Here's my `DashboardService`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { DashboardModule } from './dashboard.module';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: DashboardModule
})
export class DashboardService {
  .......
}
```

I have used that service in DashboardChild1 component, but it is giving the following error:

> WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
>   src/app/dashboard/dashboard-child1/dashboard-child1.component.ts ->
>   src/app/dashboard/dashboard.service.ts ->
>   src/app/dashboard/dashboard.module.ts ->
>   src/app/dashboard/dashboard-routing.module.ts ->
>   src/app/dashboard/dashboard-child1/dashboard-child1.component.ts
>
> WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
>   src/app/dashboard/dashboard-routing.module.ts ->
>   src/app/dashboard/dashboard-child1/dashboard-child1.component.ts ->
>   src/app/dashboard/dashboard.service.ts ->
>   src/app/dashboard/dashboard.module.ts ->
>   src/app/dashboard/dashboard-routing.module.ts
>
> WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
>   src/app/dashboard/dashboard.module.ts ->
>   src/app/dashboard/dashboard-routing.module.ts ->
>   src/app/dashboard/dashboard-child1/dashboard-child1.component.ts ->
>   src/app/dashboard/dashboard.service.ts ->
>   src/app/dashboard/dashboard.module.ts
>
> WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
>   src/app/dashboard/dashboard.service.ts ->
>   src/app/dashboard/dashboard.module.ts ->
>   src/app/dashboard/dashboard-routing.module.ts ->
>   src/app/dashboard/dashboard-child1/dashboard-child1.component.ts ->
>   src/app/dashboard/dashboard.service.ts

what am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is most likely to happen since

DashboardChild1 is a member of DashboardModule and DashboardChild1 trying to access DashboardModule by injectible. The result is Cirular Dependency.

```
DashboardModule calls DashboardChild1 
DashboardChild1 calls DashboardModule
DashboardModule class DashboardChild1
DashboardChild1 calls DashboardModule
...
...
...
...
```

the same is also valid for DashboardService

```
DashboardModule calls DashboardChild1 calls DashboardService
DashboardService calls DashboardModule
DashboardModule calls DashboardChild1 calls DashboardService
DashboardService calls DashboardModule
...
...
...
...
```

Comment: how do I use that service in the same module i.e. in DashboardChild1 component??

Comment: I believe that what you are trying to do is something extra-ordinary. Generally we do not use modules in services. I am not sure what you are trying to do. I believe that you need to clear your mind, think about what you need to do and ask a new question about it. I mean why do you need to inject your DashboardModule into DashboardService. DashboardModule holds definition of your module

Comment: I am trying to practice what's mentioned on this link https://angular.io/guide/providers#providedin-and-ngmodules

Comment: this is completely different scenario, you can have user module, but this does not has components right? this is for provider registration. In your case, you are making recursion unintentionally.

Answer (score 1):

As seen in this blog post: https://medium.com/@tomastrajan/total-guide-to-angular-6-dependency-injection-providedin-vs-providers-85b7a347b59f

You could pull out the `DashboardService` into its own module `DashboardServiceModule`. Then import that into `DashboardModule` and use it in your `DashboardChild(ren)`.